# Launch failed. Binary not found. MinGW

Tags: c, eclipse, ide, mingw

So initally I tried cygwin only to run into numerous warnings upon errors. So i decided to clean it up and reinstall this time with MinGW. No warnings! However, I still am getting the binary error. I'm going to walk you guys through exactly what I did in hopes maybe someone can find out why I am still getting this error.

1. File => New C Project
2. Named HelloW => Select Configurations (Debug and Release both checked)
3. Gross GCC Command => Browse (C:\MinGW\bin) => Finish
4. New => Class => Named HelloW (No namespace) => Finish
5. Code (Entire thing gives syntax error from main() to final } bracket) and then build

```
/* Hello World program */

#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

}
```

6. Still have syntax error, so Window => Preference => Environment (Set variable PATH to `C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_45/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Owner\Downloads;`)
7. Window => Preference => New C/C++ Project => Makefile Project => Select PE Parsor Windows and move up to top
8. Run and error.

Answer (score 0):

ASSUMING that the file name ends in `.c` and not `.c++` (which was not posted)

you opened an new `class` rather than a new `C source file` which was probably an error.

the posted code:

```
/* Hello World program */

#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
   printf("Hello World");
}
```

contains several problems. (which compiler problems you saw wasn't posted)

ASSUMING that you enabled all the compiler warnings  (which was not posted_)

ASSUMING that you setup the library paths AND installed the libraries (which was not posted)

ASSUMING that you selected one of the two configurations (debug, release) (which was not posted)

1. the returned value from `main()` must be `int`.
2. the `printf()` will raise a warning message.

The code should be written similar to the following:

```
/* Hello World program */

#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf("%s\n", "Hello World");
}
```